# "sftp" is not recognized as an internal command

Tags: batch-file, sftp

I'm trying to connect to a FTP server using the following command from a batch file:

```
SFTP -b upload_parent_child_report.ftp mhe_ipub@%SERVER_NAME%  >> parent_child_report.log
```

Whenever I run the batch file, I get the error:

> 'sftp' is not recognized as an internal command.

I checked in `System32` folder and did not find `sftp` there.
I searched my system and did not find either.
I also have PuTTY, but I need to automate the transfer of files using a batch file.

Any suggestions please.

P.S: I know there is already a question regarding this, but the solution not very clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sftp.exe` binary is by default available only on Windows 10 version 1803 and newer. Older versions of Windows do not include it.

If you have PuTTY, you have [`psftp.exe`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html), which is compatible with OpenSSH `sftp`.

So, you can do:

```
psftp -b upload_parent_child_report.ftp mhe_ipub@%SERVER_NAME%  >> parent_child_report.log
```

---

Or install the [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases) manually. On older version of Windows 10, it can be installed as an optional Windows  feature. On even older versions of Windows, you can download it manually. No installation is needed, just extract the ZIP.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply.